# Constraining number of rows to a range

Tags: sql, constraints

If you have two tables, let's just say Doors and House.

The tables are connected through a foreign key (doors to house). The constraints are that one house has 2 - 10 doors.

What would be the best way to enforce this on a data level?

Comment: I usually don't like triggers, but this sounds like a place where you might need to implement one.  With that said, this sounds more like business logic and could be implemented on that side as well.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table houses (id int primary key)
create table doors (
    id int primary key,
    house_id int references houses(id)
    )

create trigger doorsCondition on doors 
instead of insert
AS
    declare @max int, @min int
    select @max = max(i), @min = min(i) from (
        select count(1) i from (
            select house_id from doors where house_id = ANY (select house_id from inserted)
            union all
            select house_id from inserted) subquery
        group by house_id) subQuery2


    if (@max <= 10 and @min >= 2)
        insert into doors select * from inserted
    else
        print 'The insert violates business constraint'
```

and corresponding trigger for delete. You can probably merge them into one, but I'm not sure it's worth it, all things considered, in this simple scenario.